# Options to keep someone awake against their will?

Tags: science-based, biology, chemistry, sleep, pharmacology

I already asked this on Medicine SE and Chemistry SE, but both said this question is dangerous and they can't answer it, and on Chemistry I got a suggestion to ask this here again.

It is for a RPG campaing. Are there any options that an evil person could use to keep someone awake against their will? Like a gas, an injection, or any substance or simple practice that wouldn't allow them to sleep even if they wanted to?

If any costs are involved, I would like to know the most cheap and viable ways to achieve this.

Furthermore, if there is a way for the victim to be be unaware of why they can't sleep, I would like to know that too.

The technology context is 80's decade, in real world and the purpose is a that a organization want to make some experiments about the consequences of sleep privation, especially if there is a point when allucinations begin.

Comment: To prevent the question being closed as being off-topic, you would need to provide some world-building context. (Also your question as it stands seems to be story-based). Can you tell us about the technology level of your world and how this might relate to the population as a whole? VTC Story-Based, until you can [edit] to clarify. Could could look- into the [help] to get the hang of how we work and take the [tour]. Then read [about questions on-hold](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se).

Comment: You can go and watch Clockwork Orange... best example that comes to mind.

Comment: I think this may need to go to Chemistry Stack Exchange or Medicine Stack Exchange as it is a real-world question without any worldbuilding or hypothetical aspect.

Comment: @castlewrks Having to take care of a child between 0 and 3 years of age is more effective than the things they do in that movie.

Comment: @Renan, been there done that... the OP question does not indicate the evil person would have a menagerie of children for torture purposes.

Comment: Try this ancient martial art moveset of strapping oneself on a water mill so that the nose touches the water sporadically ... Ok periodically if you install a crank.

Comment: Tell the person that they must get up early (for whatever reason)...then have a great party next door all night.

Comment: @Mycroft  I like the Sherlock Holmes reference in your name. Mycroft Holmes is my favorite character in the series.

Comment: @SRM Guys, I already asked this on Medicine SE and Chemistry SE, but both said this question is dangerous and they can't answer this, and on Chemistry I got a suggestion to ask this here again.

Comment: @Mycroft Have you tried just googling "Sleep deprivation experiments"? Whatever it is your evil organization is doing in your fictional '80s, it's pretty likely that a REAL organization ACTUALLY did it, and the results and methodology are likely to be well documented by now. Any answer you get here would just the result of someone else doing that research and summarizing it for you, which would still be off-topic for this stack to be honest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Haloperidol**

[Haloperidol has a dark history of being used in torture](https://books.google.com/books?id=-L8GtJY_J00C&pg=PA390#v=onepage&q&f=false) The Soviet government would administer this drug, which is normally used to treat psychiatric disorders, but when used in greater concentrations causes intense restlessness and uncontrollable shaking.

**Adrenaline**

Adrenaline has been used many times during torture to prevent people from passing out, or to bring them back for more fun!

**Cocaine!**

It’ll really keep you awake and it’s a must have for all Latin American dictators and cartels!

**Meth**

Cheaper than cocaine.